# TensorFlow compilation error: Expecting string instruction after 'rep'

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, tensorflow, binutils

I'm trying to compile [TensorFlow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow) from source on OSX 10.10, following these [instructions](https://gist.github.com/Mistobaan/dd32287eeb6859c6668d) so that I can use the GPU. I'm using GCC 4.8.5.

This is the error that I get during compilation:
`/var/tmp//cccfsYPu.s:2774:expecting string instruction after 'rep'`

From what I've read, this seems to be a bug in an older version of binutils (at least on Linux), so I installed binutils 2.25.1 with Homebrew, but it didn't help. I've also tried including the compiler flag `-march=corei7`.

I can compile without errors with GCC 5.1.0, but I can't use this compiler as CUDA does not support it.

Comment: Are you learning TensorFlow or planning on using it. If you are learning TensorFlow don't get hung up on getting the GPU version working. Work on learning TensorFlow on the CPU and on a second machine when you have mini breaks work on the GPU version.

Comment: I've been using it, I'm just in need of the 2dfft op that didn't make it in to the last release. Apparently there are licensing issues being worked out for the CPU code, so this operation and its gradient are only implemented for GPU.

Comment: Thanks. Learned something.